# How to know the chain in the fabcar example?

Tags: hyperledger

For example, I have a `car1` that was first owner by the `manufacturer` and then it was transferred over to the `retailer` and then to the `user`

In the fabcar example, I can know who is its current owner by i don't know who is the previous owner.

Is there a way to do it?

Here is the http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html example I was following

Answer (score 0):

Is not implemented in the chaincode. To do this you could implement a new method which returns the history of the asset.

Here the link to the official documentation for nodeJS (you can find it also for GoLang):

https://fabric-shim.github.io/ChaincodeStub.html#getHistoryForKey__anchor

Here an example:

```
async queryValueHistory(stub,args){
  if (args.length != 1) {
    throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting identifier ex: CAR01');
  }

  let carId = args[0];

  let iterator = await stub.getHistoryForKey(carId);

  let allResults = [];
  while (true) {
    let res = await iterator.next();
    if (res.value && res.value.value.toString()) {
      let jsonRes = {};
      console.log(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));

      jsonRes.TxId = res.value.tx_id;
      jsonRes.Timestamp = res.value.timestamp;
      jsonRes.IsDelete = res.value.is_delete.toString();
      try {
        jsonRes.Value = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        jsonRes.Value = res.value.value.toString('utf8');
      }
      console.info(jsonRes);
      allResults.push(jsonRes);
    }
    if (res.done) {
      console.log('end of data');
      try{
        await iterator.close();
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.info(allResults);
      return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(allResults));
    }
  }

}
```